# onTouchEvent MotionEvent position is 1 pixel out

Tags: android, pixel, touch-event, motionevent

Create a simple View with a coloured background and override onTouchEvent.

Then using the Simulator, click exactly the top left corner pixel of the view (use eg “Digital Color Meter” on mac to check the click position)

The MotionEvent coordinates (using getX(), getY()) are like:

```
1.0625, 1.0869
```

(ie 1,1 as ints)

whereas they should surely 0,0 ?

Comment: Curious if you get different values with `getRawX()` and `getRawY()`?

Comment: It's the same issue with getRawX() and getRawY()

Comment: What about getRawX(), getRawY() ?